# Error 1004 when using a variable as the entire autofilter detail (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, variables, autofilter

I am trying to create a reusable sub for applying autofilters to a table in Excel. This needs to handle the possibility of multiple filters and the possibility of multiple criteria per filter. 
I have written the code to create a string variable from an array passed in. All this works.
However, when I try to apply the filter, I get

```
Run-time error '1004': Autofilter method of Range class failed.
```

If I then use the immediate window to print off the value of the string, and replace the string with it, it works.

This doesn't work:

```
.AutoFilter strA
```

But if I use the immediate window to display the value of strA

```
debug.print strA
field:=11, Criteria1:="Fred", visibledropdown:=True
```

and overwrite strA with the value of strA

```
.AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:="Fred", visibledropdown:=True
```

it works.

I have searched for an answer, and can find plenty of people discussing how to use variables for a criteria, but no one discussing using a variable for the entire autofilter.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The value of your strA is `"Fred"` or `"field:=11, Criterial1:=""Fred"", visibledropdown:=True"` ?

Comment: This will for sure not work - the VBA compiler sees `strA` as *one* value, so it passes the content of the variable as first parameter to `autofilter`.

Comment: @newacc2440 - strA is the latter, ie field:=11, Criteria1:="Fred", visibledropdown:=True

Comment: @FunThomas, that sounds fair enough. Is there a way round it? Keeping in mind the variable could equally have multiple criteria for the same field etc.

Comment: If you really want to stay with your single variable, you have to split the string and figure out the parts within your code - but probably it is easier to store the single parts in separate variables from the beginning.

Comment: @FunThomas, OK, that makes sense. I will have a think about it.

Comment: Having thought: I can't see how I can do either. The filter above could just as easily be `field:=11, Criterial1:="Fred", visibledropdown:=True` or `field:=11, Criterial1:="Fred", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="Jane", visibledropdown:=True`. It could have 10 names or 50 names. If I use separate variables or split it out later I will still have to know exactly how many criteria there are before writing the vba, will I not?

Comment: If there is only one criteria the parameter is a string: `Criteria1:="Fred"`, if there are multiple criteria the parameter is an Array: `Criteria1:=Split("Fred Jane")` or `Criteria1:=Array("Fred", "Jane")` but for multiple you need to use `, Operator:=xlFilterValues` as well

Comment: Of course, I could do it that way much easier. I had forgotten all about the possibility of putting the values in an array. Many thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Just had time to get back to this problem and worked out why I hadn't done it this way. It is because the multiple criteria may be a date range. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Ignore my above comment, I need to actually try it out first. I think I see the error of my thinking.

Comment: I am going to abandon the attempt as it all worked until I brought dates into the equation. Thanks for the thoughts though.